# Good separators for key-value pairs in English

Tags: nlp

I want to store a number of key-value pairs in a flat file. A key can have multiple values. Keys and values are in English and may contain Unicode characters occasionally. 
What are the good separators that can be used while storing these keys and values in a file, so that the separators are not encountered as a part of any key or value. For example, '&' is not a good separator as a key or value can contain an '&'.

I need two separators, one to separate the key from values, and another to separate the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agh, no! Don't invent your own format here! Use an existing one, like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), or [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). ***Please.***

I like JSON, personally, so here's a JSON example:

```
{
    "key1": "singleVal1",
    "key2": ["singleVal2"],
    "key3": ["multiVal1", "multiVal2", "multiVal3"]
}
```

Comment: +1 Or "just CSV" (fsvo [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)).

Comment: Actually this is a better idea than my one.

Comment: @pst eh, CSV kinda sucks for key-value pairs, no?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Why would it? "k,v1,...vn" per line :) But, honestly, I would choose one of the others.

Comment: But if a value contained a ',' CSV wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Is a binary file an option? Because pretty much nothing beats `'\0'` as a separator.